# Guide for API to third party application from inside Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, curl, integration

The important questions i would like to know are:

- Can I call a CURL from inside a Model or ResourceModel?
- Is there any standardized way to handle API's to third party apps?

Please keep in mind that, i already know about third party to **Magento REST/SOAP API**, what i want to know about is Magento 2 to third party APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can call to external API from inside Magento 2.
Just use `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient` inside your class.

Read more [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/485).

I have a sample project [here in my Github](https://github.com/baddwin/magento2-ongkir)